# Manejo de errores al emplear la cláusula with-as para establecer el contexto en bloques de código en Python 3?

Tags: python, excepciones

¿Cómo podría manejar las excepciones en un bloque de código cuando empleo **with-as** para establecer el contexto en lugar de estructurarlo mediante la fórmula **try-except-finally** en **Python 3**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas un bloque `with Contexto as c:`, básicamente ocurren tres cosas:

1. Se ejecuta el método `__enter__()` del Contexto, y éste retorna un resultado que es asignado a la variable `c`.
2. Se ejecuta normalmente el cuerpo del `with` (el bloque que está indentado).
3. Cuando se termina ese bloque, bien sea porque se llega a su final o bien porque se ha producido una excepción no manejada , se ejecuta el método `__exit__()` del contexto.

Las instrucciones del bloque, ejecutadas en (2), pueden producir una excepción. No hay ningún problema en que incluyas bloques `try/catch` dentro del bloque, para manejar esas excepciones.

Si no las incluyes, la excepción causará la ejecución del método `__exit__()` del *context manager*, y en ese caso ese método recibiría como parámetros el tipo de la excepción en cuestión, su valor, y el *traceback*.  Exit puede incluir código para tomar medidas ante la excepción y retornar  `True` para indicar que se ha hecho cargo. Si retorna `False` (o un valor equivalente como `None`), la excepción será re-lanzada, pero en todo caso `__exit__()` ha tenido su oportunidad de liberar recursos, cerrar ficheros o sockets, o lo que fuera necesario antes de la excepción aflore.

Si el código del bloque contiene su propia lógica `try/catch`, las expcepciones se manejarían normalmente dentro del bloque, y `__exit__()` sólo sería llamado cuando el bloque finalice (en cuyo caso los parámetros que recibe, al no haber ocurrido excepciones, serían los tres `None`).

Un ejemplo de esto último:

```
with MiContexto() as c:
     # Codigo a ejecutar
     # ...
     try:
          dato = milista[3]
     except IndexError:
          dato = 0
```

Pero también existe la posibilidad de que la excepción se produzca cuando se está ejecutando el método `__enter__()` del contexto, por ejemplo al intentar abrir un fichero que no existe:

```
with open("datos.txt") as f:
     datos = f.readlines()
```

Naturalmente puedes encerrar todo el bloque `with` en un `try`, así:

```
try:
    with open("datos.txt") as f:
         datos = f.readlines()
except FileNotFoundError:
    datos = None
    print("No se encuentra el fichero de datos")
```

El problema de este enfoque es que el bloque `except` capturará tanto la excepción que ocurra al entrar al contexto, como las excepciones que puedan producirse dentro del bloque `with`, sin que sea posible determinar dónde se produjo (aunque en el ejemplo anterior está claro que la excepción `FileNotFoundError` sólo puede ocurrir en el `open()`, y por tanto en el `__enter__()` del contexto).

En caso (poco común) de que quieras separar el manejo de excepciones del `__enter__()` de las demás, el patrón sería:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

stack = ExitStack()
try:
    f = stack.enter_context(open("datos.txt"))
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Excepción al entrar en contexto")
else:
    print("Fichero abierto con éxito")
    with stack:
      datos = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Gracias, @abulafia. Tu respuesta me aclara una gran parte de las dudas que me han surgido al gestionar excepciones. Sin embargo, aún no me queda muy claro cómo podría evitarse el enmascaramiento de errores al hacer uso de una cláusula **except** que no haga referencia a una excepción específica, como es el caso de aquellas que se colocan al final de una lista (que contiene varias excepciones).

Comment: No entiendo esta última duda, pero si no quieres enmascarar excepciones porque las capturas todas en un `except Exception`, la solución obvia es no incluir esa cláusula, sino capturar sólo excepciones específicas. Si aparece una no prevista, se elevará hasta que el programa "rompa", que creo yo debería ser el comportamiento correcto al menos durante el betatesting, para ir descubriendo qué excepciones no estabas manejando.

Comment: Cierto, @abulafia, tienes razón. No se puede prever todo de una sola vez. En ocasiones, creo que me afano demasiado en querer verlo todo a la "primera".